# How can I make the slide effect only slide 33% instead of 100% to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I've created a slider based on a pen in codepen.io to put on my website for the customer's testimonials and I want to change the slide effect in it so that it only slides 33% to the left instead of the 100% so that when someone clicks the "next" button it only shows a new opinion. Is it possible to do? And how can I do it? Here is the slider's code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
 var slide = $(".slide");
 var viewWidth = $(window).width();
 var sliderInner = $(".slider-inner");
 var childrenNo = sliderInner.children().length;
 
 sliderInner.width( viewWidth * childrenNo );
 
 $(window).resize(function(){
  viewWidth = $(window).width();
 });
 
 function setWidth(){
  slide.each(function(){
   $(this).width(viewWidth);
   $(this).css("left", viewWidth * $(this).index());
  }); 
 }
 
 function setActive(element){
  var clickedIndex = element.index();
  
  $(".slider-nav .active").removeClass("active");
  element.addClass("active");
  
  sliderInner.css("transform", "translateX(-" + clickedIndex * viewWidth + "px) translateZ(0)");
  
  $(".slider-inner .active").removeClass("active");
  $(".slider-inner .slide").eq(clickedIndex).addClass("active");
 }
 
 setWidth();
 
 $(".slider-nav > div").on("click", function(){
  setActive($(this));
 });
 
 $(window).resize(function(){
  setWidth();
 });
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(".slider").fadeIn(500);
 }, 2000);
    });
```

```css
    * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
    }

    .nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 9;
      padding: 40px;
      color: white;
    }
    .nav h1 {
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    .nav .author {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .loading {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 600px;
      line-height: 600px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .slider {
      background-color: white;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 600px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: none;
    }

    .slider-inner {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.22, 1.61, 0.65, 1);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.22, 1.61, 0.65, 1);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
          transition-duration: 1s;
      background-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition-delay: .75s;
          transition-delay: .75s;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
    }

    .slide {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #f1c40f;
      background-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1.25);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 1.25);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
          transform: translateZ(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
      -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
          transition-duration: .5s;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 600px;
      font-size: 5rem;
      color: white;
    }
    .slide.active {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
          transform: scale(1, 1);
      -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
          transition-delay: 2s;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(2n) {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(3n) {
      background-color: #3498db;
    }
    .slide:nth-child(4n) {
      background-color: #9b50ba;
    }

    .slider-nav {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .slider-nav > div {
      float: left;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      z-index: 2;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: .5;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
          transition-duration: .25s;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .slider-nav > div:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .slider-nav > div.active {
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transform: scale(2);
          transform: scale(2);
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
 <div class="slider-inner">
  <div class="slide active">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
  <div class="slide">7</div>
  <div class="slide">8</div>
 </div>
 
 <nav class="slider-nav">
  <div class="active"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
 </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get 33% of viewWidth, and should do it.

```
sliderInner.css("transform", "translateX(-" + clickedIndex * (viewWidth * 0.33) + "px) translateZ(0)");
```